# react-fullpage.js - How to load website on a certain section, as opposed to the first section?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullpage.js

**Problem:**
I want the website to load on the 3rd section, not the 1st section. Then users will scroll UP to the content, not DOWN. I essentially want to reverse the conventional order of a website.

```
<div className="section">
<h3>Section 3</h3>
</div>
```

Gatsby (React), @fullpage/react-fullpage

https://codesandbox.io/s/m34yq5q0qx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the initial section using the `active` class: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-fullpagejs-example-b618h

```
  <div className="section active">
    <h3>Section 3</h3>
    <button onClick={() => fullpageApi.moveTo(1, 0)}>
      Move top
    </button>
  </div>
```

https://github.com/alvarotrigo/react-fullpage/issues/168

Comment: I cannot believe I didn't think of active class, what the hell... anyways thanks!